# Parent component not responding to child's event emitter

Tags: angular

Given the following two components, I am attempting to listen to an event in a child.  The `CommentMetaComponent` is placed in the `CommentComponent`.

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'comment',
    templateUrl: 'comment-component.html',
})
export class CommentComponent {
    @Input() comment: any;
    @Input() eventId: any;
    showReplies: boolean = false;

    toggleRepliesListener(event) {
        console.log('in');
        this.showReplies = !this.showReplies;
    }
}

/* Comment Meta Container */
@Component({
    selector: 'comment-meta',
    template: `
        <button><ion-icon name="undo"></ion-icon> Reply</button>
        <button *ngIf="comment.parent && comment.comments && comment.comments.length" (click)="toggleReplies()">
          <ion-icon name="chatboxes"> </ion-icon> View {{ comment.comments.length }} replies
        </button>        
      `
})
export class CommentMetaComponent {
    @Input() comment: any;
    @Output() showCommentsToggle: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    toggleReplies() {
        console.log('emitting');
        this.showCommentsToggle.emit('toggled');
    }
}
```

**comment-component.html**

```
<div class="comment">{{ comment.message }}</div>
<comment-meta [comment]="comment"></comment-meta>

<ion-list *ngIf="comment.comments && comment.comments.length && showReplies" (showCommentsToggle)="toggleRepliesListener($event)">
  <comment-thread [comments]="comment.comments" [parent]="comment.id"></comment-thread>
</ion-list>
```

Upon clicking the button, I see (in the console) `emitting`, but I never see `in` logged (which I expect to happen inside `CommentComponent::toggleRepliesListener()`.

Should this work as I expect it to?  How do I fix it?

Comment: because nothing listens output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just wrote the `(showCommentsToggle)` part in the wrong place.

```
<comment-meta [comment]="comment" (showCommentsToggle)="toggleRepliesListener($event)"></comment-meta>
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried moving it to different elements before posting the question and it didn't work; I either missed that one or re-building was necessary (it's running under Ionic).  Either way, it works now - thanks!